# conditional formating for odd rows

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I would like to conditional formating for my sheet which does the following:

I'm using this condition to color odd rows
 =odd(row())=row()

I want to color the odd row from column **A** to **E** with green and from **F** to **K** with Red 
I know I can do it manually but is there any way to do it by conditional formating?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've actually got it set up perfectly right there.  Can't speak for earlier versions of Excel, but in Excel 2016 highlight the first range, then on the Home tab, under Styles select Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cells rules > More Rules.  In the New Formatting Rule box, select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" and then paste in that rule in the box.  Click format to choose your cell background color, then OK/Apply as needed to close out.